# How to redirect to a particular page when we select any option in the dropdownlist in yii framework

Tags: yii, onchange

```
   <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?>
        <?php echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($model,'name',array('desktop'=>'desktop','server'=>'server','device'=>'device'),array('empty'=>'Select Option'));  ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'name'); ?>
   </div>
```

this is my form,when i select any one,then it should be navigate to particular page(`desktop.php` or `server.php` and `device.php`)

Comment: Use a javascript `onChange` event on that select box and do a `location.href`

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `options` key to `htmlOptions` array. As Yii's official document says:

> options: array, specifies additional attributes for each OPTION tag. The array keys must be the option values, and the array values are the extra OPTION tag attributes in the name-value pairs.

Example:

```
 array(
    'value1'=>array('disabled'=>true,'label'=>'value 1'),
    'value2'=>array('label'=>'value 2'),
);
```

In your case it could be:

```
<?php echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($model,'name',array('desktop'=>'desktop','server'=>'server','device'=>'device'),array('empty'=>'Select Option','options'=>array(
    'desktop'=>array('onclick'=>'window.location="http://yourUrl.Url"'),
    //and so on ...
)));  ?>
```

You can take a look at yii's official documents for more information:
[activeDropDownList()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeDropDownList-detail)

Comment: can you give me the onchange event please,

Comment: how can i get the path(URL) automatically,instead of giving manually

Comment: @user125512 You can use `Yii::app()->createUrl('controller/action')`

Comment: how can i implement the code in my controller(please dont mine i am new to yii)

Comment: @user125512 there is no need to modify the controller. Just replace `Yii::app()->createUrl('controller/action')` with `http://yourUrl.Url` in my answer.

Comment: my view folder is "techo2pro",in that i am having three view files(desktop.php,server.php and device php).i am having one type.php in views,that type.php is having the dropdownlist,if we select any value then we have to navigate to that page automatically.can you gibe the idea.